# OutOfMemory Exception in Decoder.decodeBuffer in Android

Tags: android, encryption, decode

I want to decrypt an encrypted String, but for small data it works well, for large String data it is showing some errors like:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:216)
at Decoder.BASE64Decoder.decodeAtom(BASE64Decoder.java:153)
at Decoder.CharacterDecoder.decodeBuffer(CharacterDecoder.java:178)
at Decoder.CharacterDecoder.decodeBuffer(CharacterDecoder.java:213)
```

This is my code snippet,

```
public static String Decrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
        byte[] b = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int len = b.length;
        if (len > keyBytes.length)
            len = keyBytes.length;
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, len);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        byte[] results = new byte[text.length()];
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        try {
            results = cipher.doFinal(decoder.decodeBuffer(text));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Erron in Decryption", e.toString());
        }

        return new String(results, "UTF-8");
    }
```

Comment: Can you define "*large String data*"? Maybe in character count or size in bytes?

Comment: Actually I am parsing some XML files which are encrypted, after reading the file content the whole data is a String without any space. The size is huge and it depends on the server data.

Comment: Instead of reading the string into ram you could decode the stream onto disk, clean up the memory used for decrypting and make an educated assumption how to continue working with the XML data.

Comment: You're keeping too much stuff in memory. The base64 encoded string, the AES encrypted bytes, the decrypted bytes, the result string, ... Your implementation would benefit from using a couple of streams like a `CipherInputStream` and a `Base64InputStream`.

Comment: I added those for a common Encryption platform which is working well in both .Net and Android... Whatever the problem is solved though adding a property in the application: android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: I am not super familiar with java crypto, but I keep thinking your problem is associated with your conversion from a regular text string to a Base64 string but using an array the size of the text string element count.  Any regular string or char array will pack 8 bits per array element.  A Base64 string is 6 bits per element, so you need 1/3 more elements for the converted string in Base64 as you did for the ASCII or UTF-8 string.

Comment: To make sense of this, imagine a 6 character ASCII string.  That is 6 * 8 = 48 bits of data.  But 48 bits of data is 8 Base64 chars at 6 bits per char.